# Using a MySQL Join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a join that selects all of the posts from users I am following and friends with

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    posts a 
LEFT JOIN relationships b
ON a.user_id = b.user_2 
WHERE   b.user_1 = $user_id AND 
 b.status IN (1,3,4)
```

How can I get this query to also select all of the posts where a.user_id = $user_id (my id)?
Basically, also select all of the posts from me? Without duplicating any data.

Comment: what is your mean : "Without duplicating any data."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you basically want the results of 2 queries in one table use a union query. You would need to fix the WHERE clause in the 2nd query to be correct but what about something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    posts a
LEFT JOIN relationships b
ON a.user_id = b.user_2
WHERE   b.user_1 = $user_id AND
 b.status IN (1,3,4)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM    posts a
WHERE   a.user_id = $user_id (my id)
```

I would also question your use of a left join - I would think that an INNER JOIN would be better

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any way to test this, but I would assume the below would work as expected:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    posts a 
LEFT JOIN relationships b
ON a.user_id = b.user_2 
WHERE   b.user_1 = $user_id AND 
 (b.status IN (1,3,4) OR a.user_id = $user_id)
```